# Twitter widget, how to hide recent retweets

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to hide top retweets from the twitter widget?

This is my current code:

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'search',
  search: 'from:tackydotno OR @tackydotno',
  interval: 2000,
  title: 'It\'s a double rainbow',
  subject: 'Across the sky',
  width: 250,
  height: 300,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#8ec1da',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#444444',
      links: '#1985b5'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: true,
    loop: true,
    live: false,
    hashtags: true,
    timestamp: true,
    avatars: true,
    toptweets: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().start();
</script>
```

Setting toptweets to false only hides the text "###+ recent retweets".

Or is this something twitter includes anyway and I have to live with if I want to use the official twitter widget?

If so, can anyone point me in the direction of a good third part widget/script? Preferably jquery based (or no framework).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this very useful little exchange with Twitter dev:

https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1442

Trying it out myself - let me know if it works for you.

Yip - works like a charm - replace all instances of include_rts=true with include_rts=false in the widget.js file. (Obviously need to store it locally)

Worked well for my list viewer - let me know if it works for your TOP TWEET viewer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will test it out, just need to wait for the top tweets to show up to change the script so I can verify.

Comment: Accepted answer, anyway by now retweets are removed from the twitter list widgets. So it makes it a non issue.